# How to set emacs operator color?

Tags: emacs, font-lock

How can I set font color for operators? 
I'm programing in C++, and I would like operators such as '+', '=', '!=', '<<' and such be colored as I wish.

I tried move the cursor onto an operator and 'M-x customize-face' but it takes me to 'all faces' by default. Which is the one I should edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
;;       * the name of our face *
(defface font-lock-operator-face
  '((((class color)
       :background "darkseagreen2")))
  "Basic face for highlighting."
  :group 'basic-faces)

;; You'll have a hard time missing these colors
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-operator-face "red")
(set-face-background 'font-lock-operator-face "blue")

(font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
  '(("\\(~^&\|!<>:=,.\\+*/%-]\\)" 0 'font-lock-operator-face)))
```

Comment: You forgot `&`, `|`, `!`, `?`, and `;`.  Also, `regexp-opt` is great for making these kinds of regexps.

Comment: Facepalm. Especially since it was in the OP's request. Added.

Comment: Very grateful! Naughty comments! LOL

Comment: I cut and paste code in my .emacs and it give me error: "Wrong type argument: listp, :background". What am I being wrong?

Comment: Try `(defface font-lock-operator-face
  "Basic face for highlighting."
  :group 'basic-faces)` instead

Answer (score 0):

By default, operators are not `font-lock`ed in my version of `c++-mode` (Emacs 24.3 default). You can get the face under the cursor with `C-u C-x =`. To add font locking to operators you can add then this way:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
  '(("\\(~^<>:=,.\\+*/%-]\\)" 0 'highlight)))
```

The regex, and face may be customized. I am not a regex ninja, so the operators highlighted are very simplistic.

Comment: That didn't work for me. Emacs was initialized normally but nothing appeared different. I would guess that 'highlight just happened to make it white, the same as normal characters?

Comment: Anyway I could specify the color I like?

Comment: Sure, define a face and set it to the color you want with (set-face-foreground).

Comment: I'm totally new to emacs, so could you please explain it a little? Since I have no idea what commands like 'fond-lock-add-keywords' implies, and if it won't work I can't find a way to approach it. Thanks!